# Infinite loop issue in c

Tags: c, loops, infinite

The code below compiles, however when I run it I have an error that causes an infinite loop.  The loop doesn't even get to scanf where I should be taking in the new value instead it just always prints the prompt.  What exactly have I done wrong to cause this issue..

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//variables
bool flag = false;
int input = 0;
//function protoypes
void  get_input(void);
bool  is_valid(int);
void  print_pattern(int number);

int main(){
    get_input();

    print_pattern(input);
    return 0;
}

void get_input(){
    while(flag == false){
        printf("please enter an odd number betwen 1 and 9\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if(is_valid(input)){
            flag = true;
        }else{
            flag = false;
        }

    }
}

bool is_valid(int number){
    if(number == 1 || number == 3 || number == 5 || number == 7 || number ==  9){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

void print_pattern(int number){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < number; i++){
        printf("%s",i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The infinite loop happens if your input isn't a valid number, right?

Comment: It's doing it for every number whether valid or invalid

Comment: @Kevin , close your compiler, then open it and run this code again. It does not enter an infinite loop on mine. ( which compiler are you using anyway )

Comment: I am using the GCC compiler on our schools server and compiling it with the following command

gcc -o program1 lab3.c

Comment: Not an answer but `printf("%s",i);` should be `printf("%d",i);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fallen into a `scanf` trap: When you try to scan a decimal number from a stream (such as a file or `stdin`), but the stream doesn't contain a valid number, the stream is reset to where it was before the scanning. That means, your `while` loop scans the same invalid input over and over.

A solution is to read a string first (with `scanf("%s", ...)` or with `fgets` and then parse that string with `sscanf` or, maybe better, with `strtol`. All these functions have an error condition, described in their documentation, which you should check. There is also the issue of how to treat the unexpected end of file which you may encounter during input.

Finally, you should make the `flag` local to `get_input`. Also consider `get_input` to return the read value with a special value, say -1, to indicate end of file.

An example implementation might look like this.

```
int get_input()
{
    char buf[80];
    int input = 0;
    bool flag = false;

    while (flag == false) {
        printf("please enter an odd number betwen 1 and 9\n");

        if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) == NULL) return -1;
        flag = (sscanf(buf, "%d", &input) == 1 && is_valid(input));
    }

    return input;
}
```

(Yes, reading input other than the in a quick-and-dirty way isn't easy.)

Others have already pointed out the wrong format specifier, which `-Wall` should have caught.

Comment: Thanks this solved it.  I'm going to read into the way of doing this.  I appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop wont exit unless you enter an odd number.

Also `%s` represents string, so you might need to change your print statement to:

```
printf("%d",i);
         ^
```

Instead of do if else, change your code to:

```
flag = is_valid(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop is caused probably because you entered a character instead of an integer. Maybe this will help

```
void get_input(){
    char ch;
 while(flag == false){
    printf("please enter an odd number betwen 1 and 9\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    while((ch=getchar()!= '\n') && ch != EOF);   // this flushes the input buffer to get rid of characters. 
    flag = is_valid(input);       // This is better
  }

}
```

I also found an issue with your code.
`i` is an int but you are using `%s` ( which is used for strings ) in

```
printf("%s",i);
```

Change it to

```
printf("%d",i);
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem not in the loop. The real problem in the output (%s istead of %d):

```cpp
void print_pattern(int number){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < number; i++){
        printf("%d",i);  // output number
    }
}
```

and maybe in the input buffer:

```cpp
void get_input(){
    while(flag == false){
        printf("please enter an odd number betwen 1 and 9\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        while( getchar() != '\n' ); // clean input bufer
        if(is_valid(input)){
            flag = true;
        }else{
            flag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

also consider the following validation function:

```cpp
bool is_valid(int number){
    return (number % 2); // check number
}
```

Comment: Should be `return (number < 10 && 1 == number % 2);`

Comment: it is for Kevin's choice :-)